# No result in Gradio output

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradio

I built a CNN model classifies plant disease with set of diseases labels and tried to deploy it via Gradio library but without output What is the problem ?

After i saved the model i tried to build interface via Gradio library .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.